# How to enter username and password to login window using vb6.0?

Tags: vb6

I am working on a project where I want to insert login info programatically. Below is my code and the window image in which I want to add login info.

```
'Reference: Microsoft HTML Library
'Control: Webbrowser Control

Dim HTML As HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLI As HTMLInputElement
Dim uName, uPass As String


Private Sub form_load()

WebBrowser1.resizable = True
WebBrowser1.navigate "http://<any website name>"

Call autologin
End Sub

Sub autologin()

On Error Resume Next

uName = "user"
uPass = "password"


Set HTML = WebBrowser1.document

    For Each HTMLI In HTML.getElementsByTagName("input")


        If HTMLI.Name = "Login" Then

        HTMLI.Value = uName

        End If


        If HTMLI.Type = "password" Then
        HTMLI.Value = uPass
        End If
        If HTMLI.Type = "ok" Then
        HTMLI.Click
        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

In above code I stuck in this login window

Comment: I take it that "window image" = form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with this. For a start, you aren't giving the web page a chance to load. Execute AutoLogin() in the web browser's DocumentComplete event. Also, if the ok button is not at the end of the collection of INPUT tags, then you might submit the form without all the data.

Here's my take on the code you have shown us:

```
Option Explicit

Private Const m_sURI           As String = "http://<any website name>"

Private Sub Form_Load()

    WebBrowser1.Resizable = True
    WebBrowser1.Navigate m_sURI

End Sub

Sub autologin()

    Dim HTML As HTMLDocument
    Dim HTMLI As HTMLInputElement
    Dim inputButton As HTMLInputElement
    Dim uName As String
    Dim uPass As String

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:

    uName = "user"
    uPass = "password"

    Set HTML = WebBrowser1.Document

    For Each HTMLI In HTML.getElementsByTagName("input")
        If HTMLI.Name = "Login" Then
            HTMLI.Value = uName
        End If
        Select Case HTMLI.Type
        Case "password"
            HTMLI.Value = uPass
        Case "ok"
            ' Save the ok reference so we can use it later.
            Set inputButton = HTMLI
        End Select
    Next HTMLI

    If inputButton Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Ok button not found."
    Else
        inputButton.Click
    End If
Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    ' Handle error ... 
End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentComplete(ByVal pDisp As Object, URL As Variant)

    If URL = m_sURI Then
        autologin
    End If

End Sub
```